# Is it safe to use appleboy/ssh-action?

Tags: github, deployment

I am using `appleboy/ssh-action` for deployments, but is this safe?

I mean, I have configured GitHub secrets and I am passing SSH key using secret, but still, is the owner able to view my secret?

As far as I understand, my secret is supposed to get revealed in SSH connection string, which happens on their side right?

P.S. I tried to set it up, but after 3-4 tries, without changing anything, action returned handshake error, after that I was unable to login using my private key.